# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_mail()

Tags: plugin-development, wp-mail, fatal-error

I am using a plugin [wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart) for my cart requirement. I am trying to send an email through this plugin when some payment is made by using IPN.

My code :

```
$invoiceProducts = $_SESSION['simpleCart'];
    if(isset($invoiceProducts) && !empty($invoiceProducts)){
        $html = renderHTML($invoiceProducts);
        generatePDF($html);
        unset($invoiceProducts);
    }

function renderHTML($param){
    $IPN = $_POST;

    $name = $IPN['first_name'];
    $donationAmount = $IPN['payment_gross'];
    $contributorsEmail = $IPN['payer_email'];
    $contributorsPhone = $IPN['payer_email'];
    $contributorsAddr = $IPN['address_name'] . ', ' . $IPN['address_city'] . ', ' . $IPN['address_country'];

    //We will need to shoot email to laura of successfull payment.
    $to = 'myemail@domain.com';
    $subject = 'Donation made on your website';
    $message = '';
    $message .= '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<p>You have received a contribution from<strong>'.$name.'</strong> of <strong>'.$donationAmount.'</strong></p>';
    $message .= '<p>Contributor Information:</p>';
    $message .= '<ul>';
    $message .= '<li>Name:'.$name.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li>Amount:'.$donationAmount.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li>Email:'.$contributorsEmail.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li>Address:'.$contributorsAddr.'</li>';
    $message .= '</ul>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

But when this function is called I am getting this error : 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_mail()`

I know why I am getting this error, its just that my plugin is getting loaded first rather then `wp_mail()`.

In my case how can I call `wp_mail()` first then my plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp_mail()` is defined in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`. This file is loaded after the plugins are loaded, but before the hook `plugins_loaded` has been fired.
So the answer is: wait.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'renderHTML' );
```

On a side note: [prefix](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/) your function names and your global variables.

Comment: For more info about the requirements when using `wp_mail()`, check this out: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#notes